# Merge overlapping linestrings and retain attribute table values on overlapping segments

Tags: qgis, line, overlapping-features

I have a linestring layer. The lines are overlapping at some segments. The lines are perfectly overlapping, they don't swerve to the left/right.

I want to get the segments (500 m long, for example) where the unique route_name values on the segment are stored in one place (when I select the segment, I see '`750, 950`' as '`route_names`' field value). `Join attribute by location` tool didn't work for me

[image]